# Swift Compiler Error: Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, xcode14

After upgraded xCode to v14.0.1 from xCode 13, i got this error and can't run my app anymore, i don't have any idea about how to fix this!

is this an issue with xCode 14?
Error Message:

> Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Stored properties cannot be marked
> potentially unavailable with '@available'

Photo:
[image]
I'm developing a Flutter apps, and got this error message in Android Studio, any idea how to fix this please?

Comment: There is no "fix". This _is_ the fix; what it did before was the bug.

Comment: https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController/issues/705

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok .. i fixed this problem by changing the iOS version in file "DKImagePickerController":

From:

```
 @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    @objc lazy public var shouldDismissViaUserAction = false
```

to:

```
 @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    @objc lazy public var shouldDismissViaUserAction = false
```

Now my apps working perfectly without any issues, and in Podfile i didn't change anything, still using iOS 12

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
```

Then, run this cmd in terminal:

> pod update && pod install

Comment: thank you for your proposal. I had tjhe same issue and it works now